# Meteor iron router auto reload page

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-kitchen

I have site on meteor, with iron router as router.
Site is generated by Meteor-kitchen with my templates editing.
It works good, but if i go some way directly, not from link on the site.
For example http://hitzroad.ru/login, some time it begins reload page unstoppable.
This problem causes only on remote vpn server, on my local machine, when i develop it, theres is no problems with page reloading.
And i don't understand how to diagnose these problem.

Has anyone ideas about it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any errors in browser console or at server? BTW, I just opened your site and there is error (you wrote "slick" instead "click" somewhere in the code), but I don't think this "slick" makes your site to hang...

Comment: There is no errors, just get requests    
GET 
XHR 
http://hitzroad.ru/login [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0мс]
Заголовки
Ответ
Куки
Стек вызовов
Age38Cache-Controlmax-age=2592000Content-Length5400Content-Typetext/html; charset=utf-8DateMon, 27 Mar 2017 11:52:25 GMTExpiresWed, 26 Apr 2017 11:52:25 GMTServernginxVaryAccept-EncodingVia1.1 SRV-TMG-12, 1.1 SRV-TMG-11   
 
May be nginx try cashing some data? Because after 1 time i stop browser refreshing there is no reloading.   
And it's starts reloading after new deployment of meteor application on server.